# Solving Laplace $\nabla^2 \phi=0$ in $x,y \geqslant 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve

$\nabla^2 \phi=0$ in $x,y \geqslant 0$

$\phi(x,y)=0 $ as $x^2 +y^2 \rightarrow \infty$

$\phi_x(0,y)=0$ and $\phi(x,0)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

I know the solution is $\phi(x,y)=\frac{1+y}{x^2 +(1+y)^2}$

I want to use fourier cosine transform, so far I see the laplace equation becomes 
$\Phi_{yy}-k^2\Phi =0 $ where $\Phi$ is fourier transform in x.

Then I get solution $\Phi(k,y)=A(k)e^{-|k|y}+B(k)e^{|k|y}$

I don't know what to do next

Comment: what happens if you reverse Fourier transform?

Comment: or you could try in circular polar coords?

Comment: I can see how polar coords would help with the boundary conditions, but I'm not sure how to fourier transform in polars @danimal

Comment: i would try one or the other, although it is possible to transform in circular polars if you really want to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier cosine transform on $x$ of Laplace's equation reveals that,

$$\Phi(k,y)=A(k)e^{-ky}+B(k)e^{ky}$$

We know that $\phi(x,y) \to 0$ as $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$.  Since we are in the first quadrant only, this means that the solution vanishes as either $x$ or $y$ approaches $\infty$.  Thus, we have

$$\lim_{y \to \infty } \Phi(k,y)= \lim_{y \to \infty }\left(A(k)e^{-ky}+B(k)e^{ky}\right)=0$$

which implies that $B(k) =0$ and hence $\Phi(k,y)=A(k)e^{-ky}$.  We also know that $\phi(x,y=0) =\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x,0) &=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(k,0) \cos (kx) dk \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} A(k) \cos (kx) dk \\
&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{align}$$
which shows that
$$A(k) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \cos (kx) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}$$

Finally, we have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x,y)&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} A(k)e^{-ky}\cos (kx) dk \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \left (\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}\right) e^{-ky}\cos (kx) dk \\
&=\text{Re} \left( \int_0^{\infty}  e^{-k(1+y-ix)} dk             \right) \\
&=\text{Re} \left( \frac{1}{(1+y)-ix}           \right) \\
&=\frac{1+y}{(1+y)^2+x^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks this really helps, could you please just explain how you get A(k) from having the integral with A(k)cos(kx) equal to 1/1+x^2 ?

Comment: My pleasure.  For $A(k)$ ... What is the inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}$.  Don't forget the $\frac{2}{\pi}$ term in the inverse transform.

Comment: Is it the integral of  (pi/2)(e^-k)(e^-ikx) from -infinity to infinity multiplied by 1/root(2pi)?

Comment: The Fourier cosine transform and its inverse were used throughout the development.  So, the integral's limits are from $0$ to $\infty$ on $k$, and the kernel is $\cos (kx)$.  $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} A(k) \cos (kx) dk=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ when $A(k) = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-k}$.

Comment: How did you know this $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} cos(kx) dx =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}$  ?

Comment: Two ways. First way:  Notice that $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}$ is the cosine FT of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. And, when you take the inverse cosine FT of $\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-k}$ you get $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  They are a cosine FT pair.  Second way: Take the derivative wrt $k$ of the cosine FT ($F(k)$) of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. You get $-\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (kx)dx}{x(1+x^2)}$.  Take a second derivative and find $F''(k)=F(k)$.  Thus, $F(k)=ae^{k}+be^{-k}$.  But you know both $F(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $F'(0) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.  You find $a=0$ and $b=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus $F=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-k}$.

Comment: My pleasure!  Let me know if you have any other problems.